# Adding class variables to defined class

Tags: python

I'm a little confused on this particular problem and I have had this trouble for quite sometime now. The problem is that I don't know how to properly add a new class variable to an already defined class. In my scenario, I am using the tweepy module and using its Streaming API in order to get twitter messages that contain 'lol' in them.

**Here is the code so far:**

```
import tweepy

class StreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    #I want to add some code here in order to open a file

    def on_status(self, status):
        try:
            #Rather than printing here I would like to write to the file
            print status.text
        except:
            self.textOut.close()

    auth1 = tweepy.auth.OAuthHandler(XXXXX, XXXX)
    auth1.set_access_token(XXXXX, XXXXX)
    api = tweepy.API(auth1)

    textOut = open('twitterMessages.txt')
    l = StreamListener()
    streamer = tweepy.Stream(auth=auth1, listener=l, timeout=3000000000 )
    setTerms = ['lol', 'Lol', 'LOL']
    streamer.filter(None,setTerms)
```

Look at the comments I made. I want to open a file to begin with and write to the file. The problem is when I create an **init** method, it seems to override the original **init** method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`super`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#super) to call the original `__init__`, and wrap the file I/O in a `with` statement:

```
auth1 = tweepy.auth.OAuthHandler('CONSUMER KEY','CONSUMER SECRET')
auth1.set_access_token('ACCESS TOKEN','ACCESS TOKEN SECRET')
api = tweepy.API(auth1)

class StreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def __init__(self, f):
        super(StreamListener, self).__init__()
        self._f = f
    def on_status(self, status):
        printf(status)
        self._f.write(status.text)

with open('twitterMessages.txt', 'w') as outf:
    l = StreamListener(outf)
    streamer = tweepy.Stream(auth=auth1, listener=l, timeout=3000000000 )
    setTerms = ['lol', 'Lol', 'LOL']
    streamer.filter(None,setTerms)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can write your own `__init__` and still call the base class `__init__`:

```
class SubClass(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self):
        BaseClass.__init__(self)
        # do whatever you want here
```

If your customized `__init__` you can open a file and do, e.g., `self.outFile = open("somefile.txt", "w")`, then in your `on_status` method do `self.outFile.write(status.text)`, and so on.